# Recursively strip specific properties from object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I am currently trying to write a function that checks the properties of an object and if that property has a key 'data', apply the value of that to its parent, unless the current element is already at the object root. So, given the object:

```
{
        data: {
          user: {
            data: {
              firstName: 'joe',
              data: {surname: 'bloggs'}
            }
          },
          message: 'this is a message'
        }
      }
```

It should return:

```
{
        data: {
          user: {
            firstName: 'joe',
            surname: 'bloggs'
          },
          message: 'this is a message'
        }
      }
```

So far, my logic looks like this:

```
function stripData(data, parent) {
    'use strict';

    return Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(data).map(key => {
      if(key !== 'data' && typeof data[key] === 'object' && !parent){
        return ({[key]: exports.stripData(data[key], key)});
      }
      if(key === 'data' && parent){
        Logger.verbose(`key is data and parent is set`);
        if(typeof data[key] === 'object'){
          return ({[parent]: exports.stripData(data[key], parent)});;
        }
        return ({[parent]: data[key]});
      }
      if(key === 'data'&&!parent ){
        return ({[key]: exports.stripData(data[key], key)});
      }
      return ({[key]: data[key]})
    }));
}
```

This function so far just returns the same object that it is passed. Log statements tell me that it gets as far as the `message` key of the first object, but it has not recursively traversed the object tree by that time.

There is probably an easier way of doing this, if possible I'd like to remain dependency free, although if someone can point me to a straightforward way of doing this with lodash, I'll use that.

Comment: In your "It should return" example, shouldn't the wrapper data disappear too?

Comment: No, I'm trying to standardise data interchange, so multiple functions may return data wrapped in a `data:{}` object, which gets correlated into a single object. I want to ensure that if i forget to unwrap a piece of data earlier on, i can still clean it before it gets sent to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one seems to give the result, you need:

```js
const data = {
    data: {
        user: {
            data: {
                firstName: 'joe',
                data: {surname: 'bloggs'}
            }
        },
        message: 'this is a message'
    }
};

const stripData = (data, root = true) => {
    let result = {};
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
        let value = data[key];
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            value = stripData(value, false);
            if (key === 'data') {
                result = Object.assign(result, root ? {data: value} : value);
            } else {
                result[key] = value;
            }
        } else {
            result[key] = value;
        }
    });
    return result;
};

console.log(stripData(data));
```